# Why "TouchingDirections" script doesnt work with new physical layer?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm currently creating my first Unity project and it's a 2d pixel game. I wanted to create an invisible wall that the mob can collide with [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvCGC.png) but the player can't and for some reason, my script that is responsible for turning the mob against the wall for some reason does not work. At the same time, the collider itself works and the mob is stuck against the wall, I will be glad to hear your thoughts. Here is a link to my repository with a project I'm working at:
https://github.com/sir1e/DL

I tried to set an "InvisibleWallForMobs" layer for castFilter at TouchingDirections script but it somehow breaks projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`InvisibleWallForMobs` is on layer 3, your `castFilter` is set up for layer 6. They need to match. The `MainTileMap->Tilemap` (ground) is on layer 6 and works just fine.

Comment: Thanks to you I figured out how to properly set up castFilter at the inspector of the TouchingDirections script